# How to delay data from useContext

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My code is not setting the state of boarditems since whenever useEffect is called, currentUser is  null. How do i wait for currentUser to be retrieved before calling useEffect?

```
  const [boarditems, setboarditems] = useState([]); 
  const currentUser = useContext(CurrentUserContext); 

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUser) {
      const items = []; 
      db.collection("boarditems")
    .where("userID", "==", currentUser.id)
    .get()
    .then(query => {
      query.forEach(doc => {
        items.push({
          id: doc.id, 
          ...doc.data()
        })
      })
      setboarditems(items);
    })
  }
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `currentUser` to the dependencies array of `useEffect()`. Whenever the context changes, the component would re-render, and if `currentUser` changed since the last re-render, and is not `null` the call would be made:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (currentUser) {
    const items = [];
    db.collection("boarditems")
      .where("userID", "==", currentUser.id)
      .get()
      .then(query => {
        query.forEach(doc => {
          items.push({
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data()
          })
        })
        setboarditems(items);
      })
  }
}, [currentUser]) // set as a dependency
```

Answer (score 1):

put currentUser in the dependency array for useEffect

```
  const [boarditems, setboarditems] = useState([]); 
  const currentUser = useContext(CurrentUserContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUser) {
      const items = []; 
      db.collection("boarditems")
    .where("userID", "==", currentUser.id)
    .get()
    .then(query => {
      query.forEach(doc => {
        items.push({
          id: doc.id, 
          ...doc.data()
        })
      })
      setboarditems(items);
    })
  }
  }, [currentUser])
```